# Dataset Designer and Postgresql?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, dataset, designer

I have used Dataset Designer in built in Visual Studio 2008  for my asp.net application to interact with my Sql Server database.

Now i want to port my application to postgresql database.

Can i use Dataset Designer similarly with Postgres?

Or otherwise i am looking for an alternative tool that works similarly like Dataset Designer and help my application interact with Postgres.

Or is there anything that is  as easy and quick to learn as Dataset Designer  to help me use Postgres.

I am relatively new to asp.net programming.

Answer (score 1):

npgsql (the .NET drivers for PostgreSQL) doesn't yet support visual studio design time features. There's a commercial driver available from Devart that does though.

I use [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) to manage and design databases, though it might not be what you want if you want graphically design.